# How to take a screenshot of site which is translated using Google Websites Translate?

Tags: python, iframe, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I want to translate site using Google Websites Translate and then download it like pdf or jpg. I tried to use wkhtmltopdf, but Google Websites Translate return result in frame. Thus if I take a screenshot (pdf or jpg) of translated page I get empty pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Converting HTML to PDF may not work here.
Go for getting snaps of webpages in png/jpeg format.
try FireShot Chrome Extension.
I am not sure if it'll work, Trying is not bad.